# Persistent betti numbers and birth and death of classes

Tags: homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

I'll copy and paste the background information in my other question:

Given a filtration of complexes $\emptyset = K_0 \subseteq K_1 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq K_n = K$, we have induced homomorphisms $h^{i,j}_p \colon H_p(K_i) \to H_p(K_j)$ for $i \leq j$.

The pth persitent homology groups are the images of $h^{i,j}_p$.

And we say that class $\phi \in H_p(K_i)$ is born at $K_i$ if $\phi \notin H^{i-1,i}_p$. And class born at $K_i$ dies entering $K_j$ if $h^{i, j-1}_p(\phi) \notin H_p^{i-1,j-1}$ but $h_p^{i,j}(\phi) \in H^{i-1,j}_p$

Now we have the following:

[image]

where $\beta^{i,j}_p$ is the rank of $H^{i,j}_p$, the image of $h^{i,j}_p$.

The text says that $\mu^{i,j}_p$ is the number of classes born at $H_p(K_i)$ that dies at $H_p(K_j)$.

And $\beta^{i, j-1}_p - \beta^{i,j}_p$ is supposed to count the number of classes born at or before $K_{i-1}$ and die entering $X_j$.

What I don't get is that $\beta^{i, j-1}_p - \beta^{i,j}_p$ is the number of classes born at or before $X_i$ and die entering $X_j$.

And since LHS is just the same thing as RHS with $i$ replaced with $i-1$, I would be done if I understood the above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to know this:

> $\beta_p^{i,j}$ counts the homology classes in $X_i$ that are still
> alive in $X_j$.

Similarly, $\beta_p^{i,j-1}$ counts the homology classes in $X_i$ that are still alive in $X_{j-1}$.

Hence, their difference $\beta_p^{i,j-1}-\beta_p^{i,j}$ counts the homology classes in $X_i$ that are still alive in $X_{j-1}$, but no longer alive in $X_j$.

In other words, those that are born at or before $X_i$ and die entering $X_j$.

A good reference is [this set of notes](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/fall06/cps296.1/Lectures/sec-VI-1.pdf), pg. 130.